# Is there an equivalent of "typename" for template types?

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

We have a template member function of the form:

```
template <template <class> class TT>
TT<some_type> foo() const;
```

Now, in an invocation context where TT is explicitly specified from a dependent name:

```
template <class T_other>
void bar()
{
    instance.foo<T_other::template_type>();
}
```

Visual Studio is able to compile the invocation. GCC complains:

```
error: dependent-name ‘SomeConcreteType::template_type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type.
```

And advises to say `typename SomeConcreteType::template_type`. Which does not work, since `SomeConcreteType::template_type` is a template type, not a plain type.

- Is there a keyword that can be used here?
- Another way to make this accepted by the big 3 compilers?

---

**EDIT**: Now with a Godbolt minimal example
https://godbolt.org/z/hvbb6jv9W

Comment: `template`? ...

Comment: `instance.foo<T_other::template_type>();` -> `instance.foo<typename T_other::template_type>();`

Comment: Can we see the definition of something that would qualify as a `T_other`?

Comment: @NathanOliver As pointed out, template_type is not a type, but a template (type), so it is not accepted.

Comment: Can we get a [mre] with the code using `typename SomeConcreteType::template_type`?

Comment: I will work on extracting the minimal example, I hoped it was simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `template <template <class> class TT>`? (note the added `class` keyword before `TT`)

Comment: @NathanOliver minimal example https://godbolt.org/z/hvbb6jv9W

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Indeed, thank you for catching this mistake!

Comment: I put the duplicate back. This is the exact same problem. You have to put `template` in front of a dependent name that must be a template.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Fair enough, I needed this discussion to better grasp that it was the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `template` instead of `typename`. And, note that while `typename` would go *before* the `::`, `template` goes *after*.

```
template<class T_other>
void bar() {
    instance.foo<T_other::template template_type>();
}
```

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/ExGWdzGrq).

Comment: And you provided the solution before the minimal example arrived, congratulations!